# Smooth scrolling with prefersLargeTitles and UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, uinavigationbar, ios11

I encountered a problem with the scrolling when using the `prefersLargeTitles` and added `UITableView`.

If I set the `prefersLargeTitles` within a navigation controller and its root is a `UITableViewController` everything is fine, scrolling of the navigation large title works the same way we can see in the system apps *(in iOS 11+)*.

### The problem

[image]

However, if I use a `UIViewController` and add a `UITableView` in it, scroll seems to act differently. Navigation bar is moving more/faster than I actually scroll. It just hides/shows the large title whenever I scroll into a position that just triggers it, so I end up with the totally different feeling.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out that the layout is causing this problem.

The problem occurs if the `UITableView` use **Align top to: Safe Area** constraint *(besides the bottom, leading and trailing to `Safe Area`)* and is not extended under the bar.

However if I use the extended layout, align top to the `superview`, I can still use the `UITableView` and get the correct behaviour of the large title and its navigation bar.

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = .top
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

Or use navigation bar's `isTranslucent = true` which extends it too.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your solution? What do you mean with `autoresizing`? Not using auto layout at all? Mix Auto Layout and autoresizing masks? Thanks!

Comment: You also get that snap when using a tableViewController and setting navBar isTranslucent to false. That answer also fixes it. Thanks