# UISearchController's UISearchBar shifts incorrectly and jumps when UITableView is scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

In the video, it's a little difficult to see what's going on, so I'll try to explain it.
https://youtu.be/yOrCJB9yZlg

I have `UIViewController` with `UITableView` inside its root view. Binded via `Autolayout` (there is no difference how it's binded: to SuperView or to SafeArea).

SearchBar added like this:

`let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
self.navigationItem.searchController = search`

When I slowly scroll table, the transition between large navbar and compact navbar, and then animation of showing in and out of searchBar is too fast. Searchbar jumping in/out of navbar instead of smoothly opened/closed; navbar transitioning is jumping between two states, large and compact, without smoothly passes through the middle half-opened state while you slowly moving your finger on screen, like in system apps (Mail, Phone, Messages, Contacts etc).

I made the example from an empty project to demonstrate the issue; there isn't any changes to navigation bar logic, or any logic at all. Just two new VC's and this odd behaviour.

If i create xCode's "Master-Details" project example and add `UISearchController` to it, it will work properly. I assume its because they used `UITableViewController` instead of `UIViewController` + `UITableView` inside.

What the reason of this behaviour and how to fix it?

Comment: your question is a bit confusing. Is your problem the searching closing/opening too quickly rather than being smooth like in the system apps?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't know how to explain it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is correct. Did you try running your code in a device? Feels more like a glitch in the simulator. I tried what you tried and it works fine for me in the device. Whereas the glitch occurs in simulator.

Refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@PavelGnatyuk/large-title-and-search-in-ios-11-514d5e020cee). They have explained step by step process.

Comment: I can confirm that creation `UITableView` from code and inserting it in `UIViewController` solved my issue in the example. But I also had to create the `UINavigationController` manually from code (in `AppDelegate` create `UIWindow`, then `UINavigationViewController` with my ViewController as root). Otherway it didn't work. Very strange behaviour with IB. xCode's bug?

Comment: Thank you! By the way, a creation of all the stuff from IB is working with these settings from answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50171002/667483

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the search controller transition and tableview.
[like this](https://gifyu.com/image/WtyE) its flickering or tableview was jumping. The search controller was on the navigation item.

The key solution is to remove safe area guide from your view controller and assign top bottom left right constraints to your tableview. It will be smooth [like this](https://gifyu.com/image/Wtyr)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem and your code seems fine. This problem was already discussed **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47649375/ios-11-large-navigation-bar-title-unexpected-velocity)**.

Problem appears when you're using `UIScrollView` or its subclasses with large navigation titles. It doesn't work. Problem disappears when you use `UICollectionViewController` or `UITableViewController` instead.

Comment: Thanks! This thread is also very helpful. This https://stackoverflow.com/a/50171002/667483 solved all the problems even if using IB.
I don't know which of answers is most correct, they both solved my problem in different ways. I give the vote to Manju Basha for reputation boost! :)