# Why does my UITableView scroll offset end up behind the UISearchController when returning to its view?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

Xcode 11.1, iOS 13.1

I'm having difficulty figuring out why the TableView cells end up behind the search bar.

My setup:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Setup Eureka's UITableViewStyle to `Plain`  (like 'Contacts' app)
    // https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/218
    if tableView == nil {
        tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: UITableView.Style.plain)
        tableView?.autoresizingMask = UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleWidth.union(.flexibleHeight)
        tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
    }
    // *now* call super.
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Add search bar
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true

    // Place the search bar in the navigation bar.
    self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
}
```

[image]

Comment: please show how you set constraints of tableView. you need to set topAnchor of tableView equal to safeAreaTopAnchor

Comment: @EneaDume This VC is programmatically created, and I actually don't configure any constraints.

Comment: We need to see how is created tableView

Comment: how do you add this tableView on VC

Comment: @EneaDume It's simply inherited, as I'm utilizing the `Eureka` framework that sets up the UITableView and cells for me.  https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka

Answer (score 0):

Add the following constraints in after `tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: UITableView.Style.plain)`

```
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Comment: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x60000077cd00 "UITableView:0x7fdeb0873000.top"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600000776600 "UILayoutGuide:0x600002742060'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.top"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'`

Comment: I switched to using: `tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar`, and added your code within `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.  Placing the search bar in the navigation bar became too problematic.

Comment: `navigationItem.searchController = searchController` should work.

Answer (score 0):

After countless more testing on iOS 12 and 13, because I was getting different UX results, I discovered this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57861125/7599

Which results in:  (using [Snapkit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit))

```
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

    self.tableView.snp.remakeConstraints { make -> Void in
        make.top.equalToSuperview()
        make.leading.equalTo(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.leading)
        make.trailing.equalTo(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.trailing)
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }
```